# execute an action without redirecting

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony, twig

I have this twig that shows an action response inside an other action:

```
{% extends '::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
<a class='btn $class' href='{{ path('esp_campaign_stop', {'campaignId': campaignId}) }}' role='button'>Stop</a>
{% endblock %}
```

**the main Action:**

```
function launchAction($sizeData, $campaignId)
{
    return $this->render(
        'UserBundle:Test:test.html.twig',
        array('campaignId' => $campaign->getId())
    );
}
```

**the second Action:**

```
public function stopAction($campaignId)
{
    return new Response('Process Stoped');
}
```

Is there any way to launch my **Stop** Action without any redirection? I mean, I wanna stay in the same page from the beginning.
here is the home page where I want to stay:

[image]

Comment: Making an ajax callto the href from the <a> element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this :

```
<script>

        $('.$class').on('click', function(e) {
            var href = this.href;
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: href,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(json) {
                    console.log(json);
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
```